# Sharing / (root) Linux directory with Samba, CentOS 7

Tags: samba, selinux, shared-folders

I'm using **CentOS 7**!

I want to know if is possible share **root** `/` Linux directory.

In root mode:

```
# kwrite /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Here the line contents

```
[global]
  workgroup = MyGroup
  server string = Description
  netbios name = MyServer
  ...

[lnxroot]
  path = /
  valid users = root
  browsable =yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = No

[homes]
  ...
```

Now apply changes!

```
# chcon -R -t samba_share_t /
```

**Is smart Before sentence applying to "/"?**
Because, I had problem with the before command, and now, I can't logging with **root** user or another user.

```
# service nmb restart
# service smb restart
# service winbind restart
```

Comment: If you ran that `chcon` command, you have broken the security context of your system which has very specific contexts by default throughout your filesystem.  Try booting in rescue mode, mount your disk, change `SELINUX` to `disabled` in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`.  Then unmount your disk and restart normally.

Comment: Thank you!, Then is impossible to share "/" directory?

Comment: Not impossible.  If you disable SELinux permanently (not recommended) you can certainly do it.  if you want to keep running SELinux, it will be quite difficult I imagine.

Comment: @MikeA Do you know anything about this? - [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)

Answer (score 1):

As [*MikeA*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315523/sharing-root-linux-directory-with-samba-centos-7?rq=1#comment554551_315523) commented, if you ran the `chcon` command in your question you have broken the file labeling in your system. To restore the default file contexts you need to relabel the file system. Reboot the system with SELinux temporarily disabled by appending `selinux=0` to kernel command line in GRUB. Then follow steps in [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-867ca18a09f3103705cdb04b7d2581b69cd74c55) and reboot.

Configuring SELinux to allow samba to read and write any file is quite simple. SELinux policy contains a boolean `samba_export_all_rw` to do just that. Turn it on with:

```
semanage boolean --on samba_export_all_rw
```

For more details how to solve SELinux related file permission issues, I've written a more comprehensive answer to question [*How to configure SELinux to allow daemons to use files in non-default locations*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392834/239817).

Comment: +sebasth Any ideas - [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)