# Permissions on a folder stopping Nginx from starting

Tags: centos, nginx, selinux

I am fairly new to Linux. I have a couple of websites that I want to host on my CentOS 7 VPS with Nginx.

Nginx ought to start on start up, but it is failing due to some permissions issue, I know what file has the issue, but I don't know what the permissions should be in order to make Nginx happy.

I've captured what is happening in a [screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/JlsqgdcKdU).

What am I missing? As you can see from the screencast, `nginx:nginx` is the set user and group for all the files within the site's directory.

I assume I do not need a `www-data` user and group, because Nginx has its own user and group (`nginx:nginx`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS uses SELinux to confine http server. When you use non-default configuration (log files in non-typical locations, enable server side scripting, etc.) you likely need to tune SELinux policy.

SELinux logs policy access denials in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`) and default tools for suggestions and policy generation include `audit2why` and `audit2allow`.

Usual steps for solving SELinux permission issues include tuning policy booleans or(/and) add and apply file labeling rules. 
I've explained the topic more generally and in detail for question: 
*[Configure SELinux to allow daemons to use files in non-default locations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392833/configure-selinux-to-allow-daemons-to-use-files-in-non-default-locations)*.

I recommend checking what `audit2allow` suggests. Your issue might be solved by enabling a boolean policy option. If boolean tuning isn't enough, you need to add file labeling rules. For right file contexts consult [`httpd_selinux`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/httpd_selinux/) man page.