# restorecon does nothing on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, selinux

On CentOS 7.5, Linux 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64, I'm trying to understand how file contexts work. `ls -Z`, `chcon` and `semanage` seem to work as expected, but `restorecon` seems stubbornly silent.

For example:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir context
$ ls -laZ
drwxrwxr-x  liteyear liteyear ?                                context
$ chcon -v unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 context
$ ls -laZ
drwxrwxr-x. liteyear liteyear unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 context
$ rmdir context
```

All good, and `semanage`:

```
$ mkdir context
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_t /home/liteyear/context
$ cat /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local

# This file is auto-generated by libsemanage
# Do not edit directly.

/home/liteyear/context    system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

All good, but the `restorecon` route:

```
$ restorecon -v /home/liteyear/context
$ ls -laZ
drwxrwxr-x  liteyear liteyear ?                                context
```

doesn't apply the file context.

I've tried various iterations, with existing contexts, different contexts, other folders and files, and `restorecon` has never produced anything. There are various similar reports (eg. [[CentOS] SELinux restorecon does not work](http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/10468pnyvf/selinux-restorecon-does-not-work)) but no one seems to have confirmed there's an issue.

Is this the way `restorecon` is supposed to work?

Comment: Try "restorecon -Rv /home/liteyear/context"

Comment: `restorecon -Rv /home/liteyear/context` made no difference to the outcome

Comment: Is SELinux enabled (you can check iwith `sestatus`)? I find it odd that file context is not applied automatically on directory creation (your first `mkdir`, I assume it is in your home directory).

Comment: I did too and sure enough, `sestatus` says disabled. So it's silently ineffective? This all came about when I was trying to recreate `/var/lib/php/session` to suit nginx - it had a file context and so I set about restoring it. If you could add an answer with "because its disabled" and add why it would be disabled and whether to worry about it, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: As to why SELinux might have been disabled: the default configuration possibly prevented some application from working and the person who set the system up didn't to know how to configure SELinux; and to get the application working decided to disable it completely. SELinux provides additional layer of security by confining processes running on the system. Enabling SELinux would require you to configure your system, if it hasn't been done and the default policy causes issues. If you decide to enable SELinux, you should read the documentation (link in my answer) to avoid issues on first boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On running systems with SELinux enabled, new files and directories inherit the context from parent directory or apply a context per policy rules. Example shows that no SELinux context is applied when directory is created, visible from `ls -Z` output as `?` in Security Context column.

This suggests SELinux is not enabled on your system. When SELinux is enabled, file contexts would be automatically applied by the system.

You can check SELinux status with `sestatus` command.

If you wish to re-enable SELinux, you should check the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-changing_selinux_modes) in advance. The system should be booted in permissive mode first to be relabeled (missing labels to be applied) and any apparent issues should be fixed before switching to enforcing mode.

SELinux requires often some configuration: [you might have files in locations not included in default policy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392833/configure-selinux-to-allow-daemons-to-use-files-in-non-default-locations) or your application might require more permissions than the default policy allows. `audit2allow` and `audit2why` are useful tools when investigating SELinux logs and often reveal wrong file labels or suggest booleans which can resolve issues.

SELinux also has [*permissive domains*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-permissive.8.html) which can be used to disable SELinux for certain domains (processes) while leaving rest of the policy in enforcing mode. In permissive mode logs are generated in same way as in enforcing mode for access that would otherwise be denied. Obviously, running an application in permissive domain is practically the same as running the application SELinux disabled.